# How do i get an integer to set the value the same as a scanner

Tags: java, binary, int, java.util.scanner

I was wondering how to get a `Scanner` to set its value to an integer.

The reason I want to do this is because I have my program:

- reading a line of input that is only numbers,
- then takes the input, puts it into an `int`,
- and then uses the `Integer.toBinaryString(<name of int>);` to show the number in binary

The only problem is that the name of in HAS to be an int; it can't be a `String`.

Here's my code if you need it:

```
package base.pkg10.to.binary.txt.converter;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Base10ToBinaryTXTConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int output;

        out.println("This converts base 10 numbers to binary numbers.");
        out.println("Please enter your Base 10 Number:");
        out.println("Please wait...");
        out.println("Your numeber in Binary is:");
        out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(input));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to convert the input from the scanner to an integer?

Try:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Then you could write:

```
out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

Edit: When using `Integer.parseInt`, it is a good idea to catch any `NumberFormatException`s that may arise from invalid input, e.g. `Integer.parseInt("foo");` will throw such an exception.

Comment: it worked perfectly. thank you very much. i have a question tho. what does the `.parseInt` mean?

Comment: No worries. `parseInt` refers to the act of "parsing" the string into an integer. You can read up on it here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). In short, the method takes a string and then converts it into an integer by parsing the individual characters of the string. In this case, the parsing fails if an invalid character (e.g. a letter) is present in the string, as this cannot be converted into an integer.

Answer (score 3):

instead of getting value using `nextLine()` and parsing using `Integer.parseInt` , you can directly use `input.nextInt()`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(input.nextInt());
```

this will throw an exception of type `InputMismatchException`. if the next token in the input does not represent a value of the requested type. The exceptions that can be generated do not require mandatory exception handling.